# Qt компоновка элементов на форме

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Не разобраться мне в компоновке элементов в QtCreator. Не пойму, использую компоновки, вроде бы и хорошо, а вроде бы и нет. Есть у меня на форме `VerticalLayout`, в него добавлены элементы. Чтобы в `VerticalLayout` разместить элементы в одну строку, добавил в него `HorizontalLayout` и в сам `HorizontalLayout` добавил необходимые элементы, вот что у меня получилось:
[image: HorizontalLayout]

Кнопка "Обновить", мне нужна справа, для этого добавил `HorizontalSpacer`. Но вот сама кнопка обрезана под длину строки, не удобно... Хотелось бы сделать её немного пошире, сам `HorizontalLayout` этого не позволяет сделать. Как мне сделать кнопку шире?

И второе:
В этом же `VerticalLayout`, есть `QTableWidget`. В `QTableWidget` данные загружаются продолжительное время. Хочу на время загрузки `QTableWidget` скрыть и на месте `QTableWidget` показать `QProgressBar`. Когда скрываю `QTableWidget` (`setVisible(false)`), этот `VerticalLayout` все что в нем есть, равномерно распределяет по вертикали, этого мне не нужно. Мне надо, что бы `QTableWidget` исчез, а все остальное оставалось на своих местах!

Comment: 1. Установить у кнопки минимальную ширину и поиграть с [`Size Policy`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html) 2. Вероятно придётся использовать дочерние лайоуты либо [`StackedWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html)

Answer (score 1):

1. Размер кнопки, варианты решения

   - Самое простое решение: добавить пробелов вокруг строки `"   Обновить   "`
   - Можно установить свойство [`minimumSize`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#minimumSize-prop) у кнопки
   - Настроить для каждого элемента в layout-е [stretch factor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#setStretch)(в дизайнере настраивается в свойстве `layoutStretch`)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Центрирование `progressBar`:

   - Поместить `progressBar` на отдельный `widget`
   - туда же поместить `tableWidget`
   - у `widget` выставить свойство `sizePolicy/Вертикальная == Expanding`
   - назначить вертикальный компоновщик

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вытащить кнопку из компоновки, в её свойствах найти `minimumSize` и поставить ширину кнопки, меньше которой она становиться не будет. Обратное можно провернуть и с `maximumSize`.

Создать `QStackedWidget` с двумя страницами, где на первой создать прогресс-бар, а на второй Ваш `QTableWidget`. Ну и при заполнении прогресс-бара (сигнал `valueChanged(int)` и член-функция `maximum()`) переключать на вторую страницу (`setCurrentIndex(int)` у `QTableWidget`).

[image: Визуальный пример]